# Javascript regex to remove string inside bracket

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to remove character between `{` and `}`.

Example :

```
 input_string = "i like apple {nobody knows}";
```

expected result :

```
"i like aple"
```

Comment: There is an exact question the other day...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use

```
 var out = input_string.replace(/{[^}]*}/,'')
```

If you want to remove more than one occurrence, use

```
 var out = input_string.replace(/{[^}]*}/g,'')
```

---

To remove things between `/*` and `*/` , this one should work :

```
 var out = input_string.replace(/(?!<\")\/\*[^\*]+\*\/(?!\")/g,'')
```

Comment: Thanks..it works...

could i ask one more case..
in previous question i wanna remove char between {}, now how to remove char between /* */..i really want to learn about it..

Thanks.. :)

Comment: @guurnita: To learn regular expressions, have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions.

Comment: @guurnita: It only works if you can assume there are no nested `{}`, such as `{{}}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
let  regex = /<([^>]+)>/g;
      let match;
      let result = {}
      while ((match = regex.exec(content))){
        if(match && match[0] && match[1])
        result[match[0]] = match[1];
      }
      if(result && Object.keys(result).length){
        Object.entries(result).forEach(([key, value]) => {
          if(content.includes(key)){
            content = content.replace(key, value);
          }
        })
      }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).