# Is there a feature in javascript such as deleting words starting with "<" and ending with ">"?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a feature in javascript such as deleting words starting with "<" and ending with ">"?
For example I want to extract html codes from this object

```
      "description": "<mainText><stats><attention> 25</attention> Hareket Hızı</stats></mainText><br>",
```

Comment: Can this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648375/javascript-regex-to-remove-string-inside-bracket ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>Sounds like a job for regex.</del>

<del>I think this could do it:</del>

```js
// BAD CODE
function useRegex(input) {
    let regex = /^<[a-zA-Z]+> <[a-zA-Z]+><[a-zA-Z]+>$/i;
    return regex.test(input);
}
```

EDIT: seems like my idiot self has messed this one up. Don't use regex, as commented by someone else.

I personally hate regex, so here are some tools to help you

Website to help you get started
https://regexr.com/

And how to apply that in Javascript
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Regex code creator. It's like magic
https://regex-generator.olafneumann.org/

Comment: This is canonically not a job for regex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3001761